# AWS DMS Replication Instance quota zeroed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration, aws-dms

According to [quota documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Limits.html) the default value for Replication Instances is 60.

On my view for AWS DMS on target account I see max quota as zero and could not find any permission or configuration to allow that.
[image: screenshot of the quota zeroed]

On another account (what is the source for the database to be migrated) the values shows as expected:
[image: expected behaviour]

Other users with complete permissions on AWS account also mentioned they visualize same zero values for quotas.

Am I missing any step in order to have those available?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to **Service Quotas** and my console says:

[image: AWS Service Quotas - AWS DMS]

The quotas can be adjusted by clicking on a quota and choosing **Request quota increase**:

[image: AWS DMS Request Quota Increase]

Comment: When I navigated to the Service Quotas view I noticed permission errors, even though these errors didn't appear on replication instance page.
Then, going back to replication instance page and looking to browser console there were a bunch of permission errors, mostly related to `ec2` and `dms`.
My system admin granted me the correct permissions and everything worked out. 

Even though your answer was not exactly the solution it helped me solving the issue. Will accept as answer. Thanks!